# Internet in Belgium without residence card

Tags: belgium, residence-cards

I have recently moved to Belgium, working here for a year, with a type D long stay visa (I am not European). I rented an apartment and applied for a residence card. However, I was told it is a rather lengthy process.

I want to connect to the internet at home, but a couple of companies I contacted told me that I first need a residence card. Are there any internet companies that will allow me to connect before I obtain the card?

Comment: It's not unusual. You can show them your application or get a solicitor's attestation that your application is pending.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Just Landed](https://www.justlanded.com/english/Belgium/Belgium-Guide/Telephone-Internet/Internet), there are at least 9-12 telecommunication companies in Belgium. So if this fails, you can try another.  However:

> You can apply for Internet access online or at the chosen provider's
>   store, and you will need to present:
>
> ```
> your ID or passport
> proof of address (bill, property rental contract or bank statement)
> a bank account or International Bank Account Number (IBAN)
> ```

So while you may not have your residence card yet, you should still be able to present these forms of ID, and as suggested in the comments, evidence of your application or a solicitor's attestation of a pending application.

Answer (score 2):

I actually have never been asked for a residence card in any of my Internet subscriptions and I am currently in the process of changing my Internet connection to a 5th provider ([edpnet](http://www.edpnet.be)) (Belgian ISPs are unfortunately not yet on the same level as those in the neighbouring countries :( ) . So I am a bit surprised. Maybe you should not mention your status. I assume you have a Belgian bank account. As said, I am currently considering edpnet, but until now I had [Dommel](http://www.dommel.be), [Scarlet](http://www.scarlet.be) (The 2 others no longer exist).

If they really make it hard for you to get connected, I could recommend [Mobile vikings](https://mobilevikings.be/en/). In my opinion they are the only Belgian ISP company that already have entered the 21st century. I would be surprised if they wouldn't be able to help you. It is prepaid internet. It is going to be a bit expensive though. You would need to buy packs of 2 GB for 12 Eur.

Another trick you could use is to resort to [FON](https://corp.fon.com/en). Belgacom provides FON points on all their ADSL routers. So if you buy a FON router and install it on an internet connection abroad and you immediately have access to all Belgacom ADSL routers.

But again I think that you should simply just not mention your legal status and you will be okay to get a subscription at any Belgian ISP. Maybe you should not go to any of their stores, but try to apply online. The shops you see everywhere are really useless.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get an internet connection from Proximus before I got my residents' card. In fact, I was never asked about my status. I don't think you will have any problems.